# Intel C++ Compiler icl in Windows cannot recognize a path with white spaces

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, path, whitespace

I am trying to compile a program using Intel C++ Compiler for Windows: `icl`.
For this I need to link some libraries. The problem is that the paths of the libraries contain spaces.
The compiler reads this as different paths and does not properly link them.
My code reads:

```
icl src\*.c -Qopenmp -Qmkl -Qstd=c99 -MT -Qdiag-disable:10441 /O3 /DVERSION="\"Build date: Thu 05/25/2023 "" -link -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win"  -link -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\lib\intel64"  -link -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64"  -link -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64"  -link -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" -link -out:MyProgram.exe
```

The terminal output reads:

```
icl: command line warning #10161: unrecognized source type 'Files'; object file assumed
icl: command line warning #10161: unrecognized source type '(x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win -link -libpath:C:\Program'; object file assumed
```

(and equivalent for the other paths with spaces).
Then `icl` fails and makes `nmake` fail.
In case this is important, I execute this from a batch file.

I tried using inserting the paths in the following ways:

- `"""PATH"""`
- `"\"PATH\""`
  I also tried:
- Capitalizing `LIBPATH`
- Replacing the spaces with backlash+space (eg. `MY PATH` -> `MY\ PATH`)
- Replacing the spaces with a quotation mark (eg. `MY PATH` -> `MY?PATH`)
- Replacing the spaces with an asterisk (eg. `MY PATH` -> `MY*PATH`)

None of these combinations worked.
I also tried using `cl` instead of `icl` but it lead to more errors.

**EDIT**

I found that if I use `"-libpath:PATH"` (first comment) this error does not pop up. However, `icl` still does not recognize the paths to be linked (i.e. I can try to link a non-existing PATH and no error shows that it does not exist). Nevertheless, the next error appearing is:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
                ^
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2023.1.0\windows\bin\intel64\icl.EXE"' : code retour '0x4'
Stop.
```

But I have all the C# libraries installed and the compiler should find it in the last two linked paths.

Comment: Maybe: `"-libpath:PATH"` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it (see EDIT) and it solves the problem with the spaces in the paths, but yet the compiler, I believe, does not correctly link the paths.